# HP System Management Email notification Linux

Tags: linux, centos, debian, hp, hp-proliant

Does anyone know of a way for a HP Linux server to send and email when identifying issues such as hard disk failure? HP System manament is installed however I can only see SNMP and no email options. What would be the best solution for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you have the HP ProLiant Support Pack or HP Service Pack for ProLiant packages installed. This can be done one of several ways; tar.gz archive, HP SPP DVD, or my preferred method, via Yum and the [HP Software Delivery Repository](http://downloads.linux.hp.com).

Once you have those packages installed, getting SNMP traps and email notification is easy.

For email, simply edit `/opt/hp/hp-snmp-agents/cma.conf`

Under the `trapemail` stanza, either replace the email destination of "root" or at the OS level, redirect root email to the appropriate place.

```
########################################################################
# trapemail is used for configuring email command(s) which will be
# executed whenever a SNMP trap is generated.
# Multiple trapemail lines are allowed.
# Note: any command that reads standard input can be used. For example:
#             trapemail /usr/bin/logger
#       will log trap messages into system log (/var/log/messages).
########################################################################
trapemail /bin/mail -s 'HP Insight Management Agents Trap Alarm' alerts@brazzers.com
```

Save the file and restart the HP management agents with `service hp-snmp-agents restart`. Pull a power supply cable, disconnect the ILO network cable or something to test the email alert.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help :D