# Followup: HP System Management Email manager

Tags: linux, email, monitoring, hp, hp-proliant

A follow up question from this:

[HP System Management Email notification Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/535066/hp-system-management-email-notification-linux)

How can I receive emails from the server? Is there some software that allows you to receive, sort and filter these emails making it easy to pick up emails from many servers, either web based or client based?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use an established email address with a standard email client like [Microsoft Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/), [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), [Apple Mail](http://www.apple.com/support/mac-apps/mail/) or *even* [Eudora](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Eudora_OSE). This software will receive the incoming mail from the servers to your inbox and allow you to sort and filter by date, subject, etc.

The alert messages from these servers aren't frequent. You should direct them to an email address or (ideally) distribution group that people will actually check regularly.

A typical message from an HP server looks like:

```
To: <alerts@brazzers.com>
Subject: HP Insight Management Agents Trap Alarm

Trap-ID=3046

Physical Drive Status Change: Slot 0 Port 1I Box 1 Bay 1.
Status is now Failed.
```